# Create array from values of data fields in DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In my page there are some article tags with an attribute `data-course-id`.

```
<article class="register" data-course-id="0123"></article>
<article class="register" data-course-id="0124"></article>
```

Now I would like to generate a variable which contains an array from the article tags and the value should be the same as the `data-course-id`.

```
var array = [0123, 0124]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your title says you want an array of DOM elements, but your question describes something different. Which do you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var array = $('.register').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('data-course-id'); // converting to Number will result in loss
   // of data since what you are using is octal representation.
}).get();
```

Comment: jQuery will automatically try to parse it to a type, so the `data` in this case will be an integer, even withouth parsing with the `+`

Comment: Unless there's a specific need to import the data into `jQuery.cache`, I'd suggest using `.attr("data-course-id")`. Or even better `this.getAttribute("data-course-id")`

Comment: Well, didn't know this caching issue. Thanks guys. Any links?

Comment: @AmitJoki: There's...[the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data). `data` only *initializes* from the `data-*` attributes. It doesn't write to them, changes to them after initialization are not seen, etc. (Having it init from them was probably an API error.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, well, I wanted to know about `jQuery.cache`. BTW, thanks

Comment: @AmitJoki: `jQuery.cache` is where jQuery stores all data, event handlers and anything else that needs to be stored and directly associated with an element. Every element that has an entry in `jQuery.cache` gets a serial number that's used to look up its data.

Comment: @cookiemonster hehe, seems you are jQuery's designer. Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @AmitJoki: Probably not since it isn't part of the public API. It's just the internal data store that jQuery uses, and isn't meant to be accessed directly in production code. But if you add some `.data()` to an element *(or do a number of other things)*, then inspect the element in the console, you'll see that it has a property like `jQuery18376563829: 2`, where the `2` value is a serial number to look up the associated data in `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Nah, I just spent time early on studying how jQuery does certain things. I don't really use jQuery any more, so at this point it's just useless knowledge stuck in my head. ;-)

Comment: @cookiemonster Your *useless* knowledge was useful for me `:)` Nothings' useless when it comes to knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName("register");
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    array.push(articles[i].getAttribute("data-course-id"));
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DSU5u/).

Comment: Better off using `document.querySelector`. It has broader support in today's world (read: IE8 has it, but doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`).

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, I would do something like this

Pushing the data values:

```
var array=[]
$(".register").each(function(){
    array.push($(this).data('course-id'));
});    
alert("pushing only the data values:" + array)
```

Pushing the objects:

```
array2 = []
$(".register").each(function(){
    array2.push($(this))
}); 
alert("pushing the objects: " + array2)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9LdR/1

Comment: See comments on Amit's answer re `data`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
  $('.register').each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).attr('data-course-id'));
       alert($(this).attr('data-course-id'));
  });
```

[Live Demo Here..](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/108/)